# How to stop/cancel the download request in aws s3

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

While downloading files from amazon s3, I have tried to cancel/stop the file . But i cant get any solutions. So kindly suggest me a solution. Thanks

```
S3GetObjectRequest *downloadRequest = [[[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:path withBucket:SECRET] autorelease];
    downloadRequest.delegate=self;
    [s3 getObject:downloadRequest];
    NSData *myData2;
        myData2 = response.body;
        [myData2 writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

This is the code snippet am using for download.

Comment: What are you using to download the files? NSURLConnection? Can you show us the code you're currently using so we can provide specific advice?

Comment: Am updated my code snippet. @Matt Long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[S3GetObjectRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/S3GetObjectRequest.html) has a property called [urlConnection](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AmazonServiceRequest.html#//api/name/urlConnection). You can call `cancel` on the `urlConnection` property to cancel your download request.